# Get data from multiple sql tables using eloquent with laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

**What i want to achieve?**

Show user which pacts he is following.

**What I am trying**

I have designed two tables which are **'pacts' & 'pacts_follwers'**

Table **'pacts'** has the **details** of all the **pacts**

Table '**pacts_follwers**' has **details** of **users** **following** a particular **pact**.

These links will give you the images of both the tables

**For Schema Refer Images**
[image: Pacts Table]

[image: pacts_follwers]

So how to get pacts that user is following.

**What I have tried?**

Sql Query

```
SELECT pacts.*, (SELECT pactsid FROM pacts_follwers WHERE pacts.id = pacts_follwers.pactsid
and pacts_follwers.userid = 2 ) as pactID FROM `pacts`
```

**Sql query Result**
[image]

This query will give pactId some value, where the value is null means the user is not following that pact. If this is the solution then **i would need Eloquent for this which i am unable to make**.

**1st table pacts**

```
id
title
about
created_at
updated_at
pactsImage
```

**2nd table pacts_follwers**

```
id
pactsid
userid
created_at
updated_at
```

**Controller Code**

```
$pacts = DB::select("SELECT pacts.*, (SELECT pactsid FROM pacts_follwers WHERE pacts.id =
pacts_follwers.pactsid and pacts_follwers.userid = ".Auth::id()." ) as pactID FROM `pacts`");
```

Comment: Do you want to achieve get user's pacts - smt like`User::pacts`? You need to setup `hasManyThrough` relationship so that you can easily use `User::pacts`

Comment: Just indicate anyhow whether the current logged in user following the particular pact. No data is kept in users table regarding pacts the user is following. Everything is in pacts_follwers and pacts table. please see the images.
What I have created is a lousy solution. I need something better along with the eloquent code.

Comment: @ChiragArora you should really look into [Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships), read through it and try to understand and implement it (might fail a few times, but once you learn it, it'll definitely be worth it)

Comment: @ArunAS, thanks. I am looking at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup `hasManyThrough` relationship for User and Pact.

```
class User extends Model {

   public function pacts() {
      return $this->hasManyThrough(
           Pact::class,
           PactFollower::class
           'userid',
           'pactsid'
      );
   }
}
```

I don't fully understand if you want to achieve "get user's all pacts" or "if pact is followed by user". Either way, you need to setup related relationships.

---

Or really simple (and not efficient way)

```
class Pact extends Model {

    public function followers() {
       return $this->hasMany(PactFollower::class, 'pactsid')
    }
}
```

Now you can use something like

```
$userIdsForPact = Pact::followers()->pluck('userid');

if ($userIdsForPact->has($user->id)) {
 // your operation
}
```

---

Edit: For "if pact is followed by user", you need to setup `belongsToThrough` relationship. It doesn't come out of the box with Laravel but [staudenmeir/belongs-to-through](https://github.com/staudenmeir/belongs-to-through) package should serve you well.

After setting the relationship properly, you can use something like this.

`Pact::with('user')->get();`

Or add some methods in your Pact model:

```
public function followedByUser($user) {
    return $this->users->has($user);
}
```

Comment: "if pact is followed by user". I will learn this eloquent relationship and then i will re-attempt this. Thanks anyways.